# Wordpress Custom Menus become "Pending" when I try to run following code

Tags: wordpress

Here I am changing status of my Published posts to **draft** where post have less content using following code

```
function draftpost(){
    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE ".$prefix."posts SET post_status='draft' WHERE LENGTH( post_content ) <500");
}
add_action('publish_post', 'draftpost');
```

This code is working Fine for changing Published Items to Draft.

Issue is that this code removes my Custom Menu and make all Items in Menu to PENDING. How can I solve this?

Comment: you already posted this on wordpress SO.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78527/changing-status-of-published-posts-which-have-less-content-to-draft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extend your query.

```
$wpdb->query("UPDATE ".$prefix."posts SET post_status='draft' WHERE LENGTH( post_content ) < 500 AND post_type = 'post'");
```

Your query overwrites all post_types, including nav_menu_item.